# efficient handling of creating a template for SET command of redis (hiredis)

Tags: c++, templates, redis, refactoring, hiredis

I am new to redis. I want to write a simple library (for testing) that is on top level of the hiredis. 
for example to implement SET command I wrote the code bellow:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<hiredis.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string set(string key, T value)
{
    /* set a key */
    if(is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        reply = (redisReply*) redisCommand(c, "SET %s %d", key, value)  // c is redisContext* 
    }
    else if(is_same<T, string>::value)
    {
        reply = (redisReply*) redisCommand(c, "SET %s %s", key, value)
    }

    // and so on for other data types ...

    string replyStr = reply->str;
    freeReplyObject(reply);
    return replyStr;     
}
```

is there any better solution to handle different data types as Value for SET command? (I mean avoiding using If statements for each datatype ).
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only need to know the type of `value` in order to know what type you are inserting in your `redisCommand` string as your write your reply.

If you are restricting these types to basic types try calling `to_string` on `value` in order to build a result `std::string`

for more information https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string 
don't forget the include of course!

something like this :

```
template<typename T>
string set(string key, T value)
{
    std::string result(std::string("SET ") + to_string(key) + to_string(value));
    reply = (redisReply*) redisCommand(c, result);

    string replyStr = reply->str;
    freeReplyObject(reply);
    return replyStr;     
}
```

EDIT : Another viable solution would be to simply cast your variable each time you call 'set' and simply rewrite your function as `string set(string key, string value)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question that every value saved in redis with `set key value` is saved as string?   I mean if i use `Type key` later, it always returns string for such these SET commands?

Comment: From what I've gathered here https://redis.io/commands/set strings are exclusively used for setting.
If you mean to use it later with something like https://redis.io/commands/get then yes, the return would be a string.